# getting string length in JS

Tags: javascript

This is my html code [the code](http://pastebin.com/fEryHwv2)!
But the JS is not working
I tried a few things but i cant get the popup window if it less than 2

```
<script>
    function Check(name) {
        if (name.length < 2)
           alert("פחות משני תווים בשם");
    }
</script>

<input 
  id="Text1" 
  name="Text1" 
  type="text" 
  value="שם פרטי" 
  onmouseover="value=''" 
  onclick="Check();" 
/>
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Pass this.value to Check() function

Answer (score 1):

You haven't quite hooked up your function correctly. You need to pass a value to it. In the context of the `onclick` event, `this` refers to the `input` element itself, and its value can be retrieved with `this.value`. You need to pass that value to your `Check()` function:

```
<input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text" value="שם פרטי" 
    onmouseover="this.value=''" onclick="Check(this.value);" />
```

Likewise, you should set the value to empty with `this.value='value'` as I have also adjusted in your code. I don't know what you're intention is with the `mouseover` event, but this combination of events will only work if the user's cursor never leaves the textbox, which will certainly be counter-intuitive to many users.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a parameter to your function:

```
<input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text" value="שם פרטי" onmouseover="value=''" onclick="Check(this.value);" />
```

Comment: `this` would be a better option than `document.getElementById('Text1')`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a parameter to your function:-

```
Check(this.value);
```

like

```
<input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text" value="שם פרטי" onmouseover="value=''" onclick="Check(document.getElementById('Text1').value);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass check(this) then it will get value of that text field.

Comment: No, `this` is the input element itself, not its value.

Comment: sure, but you can use this.value